# merging with format ;string;

Tags: bash, awk

I repost my question hoping to provide now a minimal reproducible example

**Is basically doing a merge of the two files with format `NAME;URL;`?**
Not exactly, string is not required to be a URL, it is sufficient that the identical string be enclosed in separators `;`, i.e `;STRING;`

**Could you please do mention which fields or things you want to match between 2 files?**
Is sufficient to match identical string between semicolon separators from both files. For example, if `;aaaa;` is in both files then you need to carry ***from*** *two.txt* the entire row where `;aaaa;` is situated ***into*** row of one.txt where you can find the same string, i.e, `;aaaa;`

I have 2 text files

*one.txt*

```
alfa beta;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=297585;
Light Dweller;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;
Imp - Alp;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=340249;
```

*two.txt*

```
Link;1996 7.zip;https://yd.k/d/BbNUb-2yhVmVnw;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;
Link;Moonblo (Tape)_123.zip;https://yd.k/d/57i;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;
Link;Moonblo(Demo) [1996].rar;https://yd.k/d/A7U;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;
```

I try to generate this expected output text

```
alfa beta;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=297585;
Light Dweller;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;Link;1996 7.zip;https://yd.k/d/BbNUb-2yhVmVnw;Link;Moonblo (Tape)_123.zip;https://yd.k/d/57i;Link;Moonblo(Demo) [1996].rar;https://yd.k/d/A7U;
Imp - Alp;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=340249;
```

but script truncate strings and generates this wrong output so something don't works:

```
alfa beta;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=297585;;;
Light Dweller;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=3869;;;
Imp - Alp;https://123.org/a/in.ph?shw=340249;;;
```

I use 2 scripts: join.awk (is needed to preserve row ordering)

```
BEGIN {
  OFS=FS=";"
}
ARGIND == 1 {
   map[$2] = ($2 in map ? map[$2] OFS : "") $1
   next
}
{
   r = $0;
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i in map)
         r = r OFS map[$i]
   $0 = r
}
1
```

and join.sh (main script)

```
#! /usr/bin/awk  -f

BEGIN {
  OFS=FS=";"
  C=0;
}
{
  if (ARGIND == 1) {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     if (T1[X]) {
        T1[X] = T1[X] $0
     } else {
        T1[X] = $0
     }
  } else {
     X = $NF
     T0[$NF] = C++
     $NF = ""
     if (T2[X]) {
        T2[X] = T2[X] $0
     } else {
        T2[X] = $0
     }
  }
}

END {
  for (X in T0) {
    # concatenate T1[X] and X, since T1[X] ends with ";"
    print T1[X]  X, T2[X]
  }
}
```

I use it in this way

```
awk -f join.awk two.txt one.txt > "three.txt"
```

**Examples of text files that allow me to generates correct output:**

For example, if I have these 2 files text, after running scripts, I can get correct output

*one.txt*

```
alfa beta;www.google.com
Light Dweller - CR, Technical Metal;http://alfa.org;http://beta.org;http://gamma.org;
```

*two.txt*

```
Jack to ride.zip;http://alfa.org;
JKr.rui.rar;http://gamma.org;
Nofj ogk.png;http://gamma.org;
```

Command to generate output (for example three.txt)

```
awk -f join.awk two.txt one.txt > "three.txt"
```

CORRECT OUTPUT, this is expected sample output example

```
Light Dweller - CR, Technical Metal;http://alfa.org;http://beta.org;http://gamma.org;;Jack to ride.zip;http://alfa.org;JKr.rui.rar;http://gamma.org;Nofj ogk.png;http://gamma.org;
alfa beta;www.google.com;
```

but in my situation I can't, my 2 text files prevent me from doing it, I don't understand why

**added logic of getting expected output**

> If there is an identical string in one line of text file two.txt that matches the one found in file one.txt, then the entire line of text file two.txt must appear on line of text file one.txt. All this, however, by generating a third file called three.txt and not modifying the one.txt file Once this is done, it is necessary to eliminate the duplicates present on that row and for any other rows.

**explanation and application**

For example, you can see that the string enclosed by the semicolon separator ;

```
http://gamma.org
```

is present in both text files. In the case of one.txt this string is found on the second line while in two.txt the same string is found both on the second and on the third line.

What is special about the three.txt file?

- the lines having the strings in common are grouped on a single line and only on a single line in the whole text file. Hence, the string

  `http://gamma.org`

it will be present only once, it cannot be on a different line.

- duplicates are removed, for example the string

  `http://gamma.org`

it only appears once on the same line, in other words we can't have something like this

```
http://gamma.org;JKr.rui.rar;http://gamma.org
```

because the string would be repeated (and I don't want duplicates).